# How to move screen up and down in android with table or grid layout?

Tags: android

I have  a grid layout contain some image_buttons(icons) , When i execute application in emulator or in my android device (Galaxy S4), I can't move screen up or down to see all image buttons  ( I tried to use table layout but the same problem ).

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <GridLayout
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
        p1:rowCount="4"
        p1:columnCount="2">
        <ImageButton
            p1:src="@drawable/main_phonedic"
            p1:layout_column="0"
            p1:id="@+id/layout1_ImgBut_Phone"
            p1:layout_margin="20dp"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        <ImageButton
            p1:src="@drawable/mainservices"
            p1:id="@+id/layout1_ImgBut_ElectronicService"
            p1:layout_margin="20dp"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        <ImageButton
            p1:src="@drawable/main_forms"
            p1:layout_column="0"
            p1:id="@+id/layout1_ImgBut_Forms"
            p1:layout_margin="20dp"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        <ImageButton
            p1:src="@drawable/main_recivetables"
            p1:id="@+id/layout1_ImgBut_ReciveTable"
            p1:layout_margin="20dp"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        <ImageButton
            p1:src="@drawable/main_problems"
            p1:layout_column="0"
            p1:id="@+id/layout1_ImgBut_Problem"
            p1:layout_margin="20dp"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        <ImageButton
            p1:src="@drawable/main_info"
            p1:id="@+id/layout1_ImgBut_Myinf"
            p1:layout_margin="20dp"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        <ImageButton
            p1:src="@drawable/maincontact"
            p1:layout_column="0"
            p1:id="@+id/layout1_ImgBut_contact"
            p1:layout_margin="20dp"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:background="@android:color/transparent"
            p1:layout_span="2" />
    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: To move screen up and down ,add a ScrollView

Comment: Thanks a lot, it Works .

Answer (score 0):

You just need a ScrollView to contain GridLayout.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it Works .